# Merge multiple tags for JS Test Driver

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

It appears that the tags [jstestdriver](/questions/tagged/jstestdriver) and [js-test-driver](/questions/tagged/js-test-driver) should be merged.

Answer (score 3):

Done. Merged [jstestdriver](/questions/tagged/jstestdriver) -> [js-test-driver](/questions/tagged/js-test-driver) for ease of readability.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  For the future, this is the proper procedure for tag merging, at least until I have the privilege myself, correct?

Comment: @DJQuimby Yep, this is fine. :)